# Sinon stub of express route does not get called

Tags: node.js, express, sinon, sinon-chai

I am currently tinkering around with sinon/mocha/chai on an express webapp.
I am trying to verify that the authentication works properly in that way that I let the authentication middleware run normally and have the request blocked and on another run I stub the middleware function and just let request with additional information pass.

Basically my setup looks like this:

*helper.js* with the function to be stubbed

```
var helper = {};

helper.verifyAuthCookie = function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.signedCookies.auth) {
    jwt.verify(req.signedCookies.auth, "secret", {
      subject: "a",
      issuer: "b",
      audience: "c"
    }, function(err, decoded) {
      if (decoded) {
        req.user = {
          authenticated: true
        };
      } else {
        req.user = {
          authenticated: false
        };
      }
      next();
    });
  } else {
    req.user = {
      authenticated: false
    };
    next();
  }
};

module.exports = helper;
```

*test.js*

```
var helper=require("helper.js");
describe("get unauthenticated", function() {
  it("should fail", function(done) {
    chai.request(server.app)
      .get("/queries")
      .end(function(err, res) {
        expect(err)
          .to.not.be.null;
        expect(res.status)
          .to.be.equal(401);
        done();
      });
  });
});
describe("get unauthenticated", function() {
  var verifyCookieStub;
  beforeEach(function() {
    verifyCookieStub = sandbox.stub(helper, "verifyAuthCookie", function(req, res, next) {
      req.user = {
        authenticated: true
      }
      next();
    });
  });
  afterEach(function() {
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(verifyCookieStub);
    verifyCookieStub.restore();
  });
  it("should not fail", function(done) {
    chai.request(server.app)
      .get("/queries")
      .end(function(err, res) {
        expect(err)
          .to.be.null;
        expect(res.status)
          .to.be.equal(200);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

and inside the express web app server.js

```
const express = require("express");
const helper = require("./helper.js");
app = express();
app.use(helper.verifyAuthCookie);

app.get("/queries", function(req, res) {
  res.send(req.user.authenticated);
});
```

The problem now is that, the first test succeeds but the second and the afterEach assertions both fails which indicates the stub didn't work properly.

While searching around on the internet I found someone who is doing something very very similar and his seemed to work fine. His [Github Repo](https://github.com/alexjamesbrown/supertest-stubbing-middleware)

Do I miss something entirely?